# contar propiedades especificas de un objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Necesito saber cuantos contenedores tiene un objeto con javascript, puedo contar las propiedades en general pero no logro contar solo las del parametro "Contenedores"

abajo pongo un array similar a lo que necesito donde tengo 4 propiedades y una de ellas es contendeores, entonces, quiero contar cuantos contenedores hay

```
[
  {
    "depositoId": 47,
    "idLugarRecepcionCargar": 119,
    "idPuertoDestinoFinal": 87,
    "Contenedores":[
        {
            "numeroContenedor": "GESU9586507",
            "tipoContenedorId": 1,
            "Temperatura": "3.5",
            "MedidaTemp": "C",
            "Ventilacion": "15.000",
            "MedidaVent": "CBM",
            "ODos": null,
            "CoDos": null
        },
        {
            "numeroContenedor": "GESU9592507",
            "tipoContenedorId": 1,
            "Temperatura": "3.5",
            "MedidaTemp": "C",
            "Ventilacion": "15.000",
            "MedidaVent": "CBM",
            "ODos": null,
            "CoDos": null
        },
        {
            "numeroContenedor": "GESU9598707",
            "tipoContenedorId": 1,
            "Temperatura": "3.5",
            "MedidaTemp": "C",
            "Ventilacion": "15.000",
            "MedidaVent": "CBM",
            "ODos": null,
            "CoDos": null
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: No podemos ayudarte si no subes el código que usas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
console.log("Contenedores:" + array[0].Contenedores.length);
```

```js
var array = [
  {
    "depositoId": 47,
    "idLugarRecepcionCargar": 119,
    "idPuertoDestinoFinal": 87,
    "Contenedores":[
        {
            "numeroContenedor": "GESU9586507",
            "tipoContenedorId": 1,
            "Temperatura": "3.5",
            "MedidaTemp": "C",
            "Ventilacion": "15.000",
            "MedidaVent": "CBM",
            "ODos": null,
            "CoDos": null
        },
        {
            "numeroContenedor": "GESU9592507",
            "tipoContenedorId": 1,
            "Temperatura": "3.5",
            "MedidaTemp": "C",
            "Ventilacion": "15.000",
            "MedidaVent": "CBM",
            "ODos": null,
            "CoDos": null
        },
        {
            "numeroContenedor": "GESU9598707",
            "tipoContenedorId": 1,
            "Temperatura": "3.5",
            "MedidaTemp": "C",
            "Ventilacion": "15.000",
            "MedidaVent": "CBM",
            "ODos": null,
            "CoDos": null
        }
    ]
  }
]

console.log("Contenedores:" + array[0].Contenedores.length);
```

Espero te sirva la respuesta, Recuerda que el [0] debe cambiar siempre y cuando esperes varios objetos para ello puedes hacerlo con un **For**, Saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué votan como mala la respuesta?, le he dado un ejemplo claro de contar cuantos contenedores tiene en su JSON.

Comment: Me sirvió gracias sabia que la respuesta era simple pero yo me estaba complicando y yéndome por otros lados, nuevamente gracias

Comment: Es un placer, cuídate.

Comment: tal vez se esperaba un `array.forEach(ele =>  console.log("Contenedores:" + ele.Contenedores.length));`

Comment: Si tal vez, buscaba simplificar un poco en vez de hacer un for, lo importante es que ha entendido como puede hacerlo de ambas maneras.